# Slide Div Left to Right from Menu Buttons

Tags: html, menu, jquery-animate

As you can see in JSFiddle I have slideout menu. I want to slide or animated left to the right opening "div" on my page center, when someone click menu buttons. I've already searched about that but always saw lightbox but I dont want it. By the way I cannot add JSFiddle link so I have to write it like that. h ttp://jsfiddle.net/ygzsmsk/4b2Zs/

Comment: Sorry I do not understand. You want the entire page to move from left to right?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your question, I've modified your code a bit.
I understood that you want the first div to move from left to right instead of just the menu.

You need to remove the position CSS attributes from internal elements and add the same to your parent div; in addition, you need to have your JS act on the parent div.

Have a look at this:

```
.cbp-spmenu-push {
    left: -200px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4b2Zs/1/

You can play around with the final arrangements as you see fit.

Comment: Nope not this sorry. When click menu buttons I want to div area which appears on center of page. For page contents. Sorry about my bad English